# How to add a product can be add to quote?

Tags: product, virtocommerce

Does any one know to config a product can be "Add to quote"?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For current storefront implementation any product can be added to a quote request by default. You can enable or disable quote requests for a whole store in VirtoCommerce Manager (**Browse** > **Stores** > **Your store** > **Dynamic properties** widget > **EnableQuotes** switcher). Product property **IsQuotable** (or its analog) will be implemented later.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.